# How to deal with WhiteSpaces in directory when calling a function from a module

Tags: python, bash

I have a code where I call a `Node` script. The `javaScript` named `preprocess_latex.js` is in the same directory as `filter_tokenize.py`. Every directory has `__init__.py` so I can call the modules.

My code looks like this:

```
def tokenize(latex:str,kind:str='normalize')->list:
    '''
    Tokenize the incoming LaTex. This uses subscripts based on Node and Perl which uses bash call to KaTex. It also creates 2 .lst files in the same directory where the function is being called
    args:
        latex: Latex string
    out:
        List of cleaned tokens per LaTex
    '''
    path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute() # When you call this module, it'll give the path of THIS file instead of the Current Working Directory
    output_file = os.path.join(path,'out.lst')
    input_file = os.path.join(path,'input_file.lst')
    js_file_path = os.path.join(path,"preprocess_latex.js").replace(' ','\\ ')

    with open(input_file,'w') as f:
        f.write(latex+'\n')

    cmd = "perl -pe 's|hskip(.*?)(cm\\|in\\|pt\\|mm\\|em)|hspace{\\1\\2}|g' %s > %s"%(input_file, output_file) # Call Perl subscript
    ret = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    cmd = f"cat {temp_file} | node {js_file_path} {kind} > {output_file} "
    ret = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Problem is that I have spaces in my directories and when I do:

```
from latex_utils.filter_tokenize import *
tokenize('some_string')
```

it gives me error as:

```
Can't open Improve/Latex/latex_simialarity/latex_utils/input_file.lst: No such file or directory.
Can't open Improve/Latex/latex_simialarity/latex_utils/out.lst: No such file or directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/admin1/Desktop/Work/Search Improve/Latex/latex_simialarity/latex_utils/filter_tokenize.py", line 31, in tokenize
    with open(output_file) as fin:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/admin1/Desktop/Work/Search Improve/Latex/latex_simialarity/latex_utils/out.lst'
```

I tried with `output_file.replace(' ','\\ ')` and there was a different error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/admin1/Desktop/Work/Search Improve/Latex/latex_simialarity/latex_utils/filter_tokenize.py", line 23, in tokenize
    with open(input_file,'w') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/admin1/Desktop/Work/Search\\ Improve/Latex/latex_simialarity/latex_utils/input_file.lst'
```

Comment: You need to escape spaces with backslash, not forward slash. Or put the filename in quotes.

Comment: `replace(' ','\/ ')` should be `replace(' ','\\ ')`

Comment: @Barmar sorry! that was a typo

Comment: you could use `__import__(path_to_file)`